# running thermal printer in raspberry pi detecting some problems

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, printers, thermal-printer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/print.py", line 7, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=10000)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

Comment: Do you have any question related to software development? Is there any code you can show us?

Comment: Hmm, i'm not really sure what you want, but based on the error I think you're opening the wrong port. Maybe you can share the code with us?

Comment: `No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'` is pretty clear. It states that `/dev/ttyUSB0` isn't present. Probably because it is just mounted somewhere else within the `/dev/` directory. You will need to find the right directory for your printer.